# Docker prune containers not used in the last X hours

Tags: docker

I would like to periodically clean up after Docker, as I use it fairly extensively and have lots of unused images/volumes.

I know about the existence of the `docker system prune` command, which would almost be what I need. However, I have a few containers that are run on a schedule and exit almost immediately. They are some maintenance scripts that run once per hour/once per day. If I use the 'standard' prune command, they get deleted and have to be created all over again. I also found the `until=` filter to be useless in this case, since the containers have been created months ago but are used daily.

Is there a way to tell Docker to delete all containers that are Exited by more than X hours? Which for example could delete all containers not used in the last day, for example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Create a container" is not supposed to be a heavy-weight operation.  Consider using `docker run --rm` to delete short-lived containers immediately after they exit, and recreating them on every run.

Comment: @DavidMaze I agree on the ephimeral nature of containers, I'm using them this way not to store data between executions but just to avoid writing in different scripts the docker run command with all the needed parameters. I have the container created and mounted with all the required volumes, then, when needed, it gets run and does its routine, then exits again. I'm open to suggestions if there are better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do it with the prune command. But, how about listing all the exited containers in json format, selecting the ones that exited "day" or "month" ago with jq, and then removing them?

```
docker container ls -a --filter 'status=exited' --format '{{ json . }}' \
| jq --slurp --raw-output '.[] | select(.Status | contains("day") or contains("month")) | .ID' \
| xargs docker container rm
```

Note that just removing the exited containers won't cover ones in other non-running states. The possible states are `created`, `restarting`, `running`, `removing`, `paused`, `exited`, and `dead`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use a container orchestrator/schedular , instead of doing things like that manually. For example you can use kubernetes cron jobs.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Does something exist like this for vanilla Docker? I'm using https://hub.docker.com/r/blacklabelops/jobber/ to run containers on a schedulation, but it doesn't have the syntax to launch containers as seen in your link. I wouldn't want to add the complexity of a Kubernetes cluster on a personal development machine, for something like this especially.

Comment: for development you can do it on minikube